# Prevent axios/fetch redirection

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, axios

I have a little problem with my app:
I have to get some cookies given in the response of one URL, which is obtained by making a request to another URL. The request is done, but I'm not able to get the cookies, because when I get the result of my request, I get redirected to/of the site.
**So my question is**: is there a way to authorize the first redirection, but not the second?

I'm using react-native, and the Axios solution `maxRedirects: 1` is not working in my case. Same for the `redirect: 'manual'` in fetch.

The request code:

```
fetch(
                    'https://gitlab.blablabla.fr/users/auth/ldapmain/callback',
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'accept-charset':'utf-8',
                        },
                        body: querystring.stringify({
                            authenticity_token: this.state.token,
                            username: this.state.username,
                            password: this.state.password,
                        }),
                        redirect: 'manual',
                        credentials: 'include',
                        withCredentials: 'true',

                    }
                ).then( (responseData2) => {
                        console.log(this.state.username +"/"+ this.state.password+ "/"+this.state.token + "/"+ this.state.utf8);
                        console.log(responseData2);


                    })
```

And the response that is shown:

```
Response {
  type: 'default',
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: undefined,
  headers: 
   Headers {
     map: 
      { 'x-version-id': [Object],
        server: [Object],
        'cache-control': [Object],
        date: [Object],
        'content-type': [Object],
        'content-length': [Object],
        'content-security-policy': [Object],
        'accept-ranges': [Object],
        'x-request-id': [Object],
        'last-modified': [Object],
        'x-frame-options': [Object] } },
  url: 'https://mattermost.blablabla.fr/',
  _bodyInit: '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> the html code</html> ',
  _bodyText: '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> the html code</html> ' }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having a very similar issue.

Comment: Hi, i didn't find any solutions, but i passed around by using Cookies instead of it. :/ Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to handle the redirection manually by checking the response status and headers. You can modify your code to follow the redirection manually and capture the cookies from the headers.

```
fetch('https://gitlab.blablabla.fr/users/auth/ldapmain/callback', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'accept-charset': 'utf-8',
  },
  body: querystring.stringify({
    authenticity_token: this.state.token,
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  }),
  credentials: 'include',
})
  .then((response) => {
    // Check if the response is a redirect
    if (response.redirected) {
      // Manually follow the redirection
      return fetch(response.url, {
        method: 'GET', // or 'POST' if needed
        credentials: 'include',
      });
    } else {
      return response;
    }
  })
  .then((responseData) => {
    // Now you can access the cookies from the headers
    const cookies = responseData.headers.get('set-cookie');
    console.log('Cookies:', cookies);

    // Continue handling the response as needed
    console.log(responseData);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my code, I can solve, prevent the fetch redirectiong.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
fetch('/api/user/get_user_profile', 
    { 
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            sHash: sHash
        }),
        redirect: 'manual',
    }
)
```

This is backend code

```
res.status(200);
res.send(content);
return;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yptGN.png)

Comment: HTTP status ```200``` is not part of "redirect" types, ```3**``` is .